# Move image when scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

How can I make the image mode when I scroll the page and when it hits the top page.
I want the rate arrow up and down to move along the top page without dissapering when I scroll it.

BTW I am using JQuery for the movement

[image]

[image]

```
  <div class="FirstChildBox">
                <div class="imageBox">
                       <img src="textimage2.jpg" id="imageBoxImg"/>
                    <form>
                            <label class="Image1BoxLabel"><input type="checkbox"/>Image1</label>
                        <label class="Image1BoxLabel"><input type="checkbox"/>Image1</label>
                        <label class="Image1BoxLabel"><input type="checkbox"/>Image1</label>1
                        </form>
                        <a href="#">Enemy1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="rateImage">
                    <div class="arrowupdownrate">
                        <div class="upArrow" id="upArrow"><img src="up_down.png" /> </div>
                        <div class="rateNumber"><a>112320</a></div>
                        <div class="downArrow" id="downArrow"><img src="red_down.png" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the `rateImage` to the top right hand corner of the nearest `relative` parent. In this case, the document.

```
.rateImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
.rateImage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

I prefer `position: absolute;`, simply because it ends up being more flexible in the long run. It really doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: it didnt stop after it hit the maximum height it only stays at top

Answer (score 0):

Give position: fixed to the rate div

```
.rateImage {
 position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: it didnt stop after it hit the maximum height it only stays at top

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `upArrow` and `downArrow` css classes:

```
position: fixed
```